# Why does my little code give me this warning

Tags: c++, windows

why does the compiler give me a warning in line 17:

```
Object_OutherClass.Object_InnerClass.SetZwischenspeicher(17);
```

It says:

> C6001: Not initialized storage is being used.

If anyone could help me that would be so cool but pls dont say Im a Noob, im just learning

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class OutherClass {
 public:
  class InnerClass {
   private:
    double Zwischenspeicher;

   public:
    void SetZwischenspeicher(double zahl) { Zwischenspeicher = zahl; }
    double getZwischenspeicher() { return this->Zwischenspeicher; }
  } Object_InnerClass;
};
int main() {
  OutherClass Object_OutherClass;
  Object_OutherClass.Object_InnerClass.SetZwischenspeicher(17);
  std::cout << Object_OutherClass.Object_InnerClass.getZwischenspeicher()
            << std::endl;
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6001?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ok this means i have to define a constructor an call it by declaration ?

Comment: @sigmund The code looks fine to me. [I don't get any warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LHB2KM) What version of VS do you use?

Comment: There's no uninitialized usage in the shown code. The compiler is wrong.

Comment: Im using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - I dont know exact version

Comment: Which variable is mentioned in the error [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6001?view=vs-2019) ("warning C6001: using uninitialized memory <variable>").

Comment: Please avoid `using namespace std;`.  It is considered bad practice and will ruin your life.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)